# Sumar resultados de un SUM en SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Necesito hacer una sumar una serie de elementos que de hecho son resultado de una suma, trataré de explicarme lo mejor posible.

Tengo el siguiente query:

```
select distinct 
cp.descripcion,
cp.idSysCPPuestos,
 em.nombreLargo
,sum(CAST(em.sueldoDiario AS DECIMAL(18, 4)))+sum(CAST(em.sueldoIntegrado AS DECIMAL(18, 4))) [Total]
    

 from 
sysCPEmpleados em 
inner join sysCPCentroCosto cc on
em.idSysCPCentroCosto = cc.idSysCPCentroCosto
inner join sysCPPuestos cp on
em.idSysCPPuestos = cp.idSysCPPuestos

where cc.idSysCPCentroCosto = 'SBIB15C'



 group by 
    cp.descripcion,
    cp.idSysCPPuestos,
    em.nombreLargo
    ,em.idSysCPCentroCosto
```

Me devuelve lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La cuestión es que necesito obtener el total de los datos por su **idSysCPPuestos**, es decir la suma de todos esos **total** es para obtener algo como:

> AFANDORA | GB022 | x.xx
>
> AYUDANTE | GB025 | x.xx

Evitar que se repitan que solo me muestré el total de las sumas "suamdas entre si".

Comment: Lo que necesitas es quitar el campo nombreLargo y sumar todos los totales y quitar los duplicados con los totales ya sumados?

Comment: @Ricardo si, el NOMHBRELARGO es una referencia para mi, no es relevante

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para ello lo que necesitas es apoyarte en un select mayor del mismo select que has hecho, en el cual agruparías como necesites, sumando al final. De la siguiente forma:

```
select x.descripcion, x.idSysCPPuestos, SUM(Total)
from(
    select cp.descripcion,
        cp.idSysCPPuestos,
        em.nombreLargo, 
        sum(CAST(em.sueldoDiario AS DECIMAL(18, 4))) + sum(CAST(em.sueldoIntegrado AS DECIMAL(18, 4))) [Total]
    from sysCPEmpleados em 
    inner join sysCPCentroCosto cc 
        on em.idSysCPCentroCosto = cc.idSysCPCentroCosto
    inner join sysCPPuestos cp 
        on em.idSysCPPuestos = cp.idSysCPPuestos
    where cc.idSysCPCentroCosto = 'SBIB15C'
    group by 
        cp.descripcion,
        cp.idSysCPPuestos,
        em.nombreLargo
        ,em.idSysCPCentroCosto
) as x
group by x.descripcion, x.idSysCPPuestos
```

Espero te haya servido mi ayuda. Saludos.

**NOTA:** Si ya haces una agruapción de tu SELECT bajo los mismos campos, está demas el **distinct** a ese nivel.